# Moksha in the Vedas (excluding the Upanishads)

Tags: vedas, vedanta, moksha, brahman

Note that this is not a dup of [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9827/do-vedas-talk-about-moksha-kaivalya-or-mukti), since the answers I expect are not from the Upanishads.

I have two questions based on my (poor) understanding of a few posts in this site. They are related and hence asking in one post.

For the matter of this post, I define a Vedantic scripture to be all of the Upanishads, The BrahmaSutra and the Bhagavad Gita (of Krishna) combined.

1. Is there a Vedic (non-Vedantic) scripture that talks about the concept of Moksha (the attainment of status equal/identical to Brahman)? I am not referring to the MahaMrtyunjaya stotram which means something slightly different (IMHO based on my reading of Sanskrit).
2. If there is none, what is the purely Vedic (non-Vedantic) thought about what happens after death?

I would greatly appreciate references to the scriptures with locations so that I can read up the verses and understand as much as I can.

(I am curious to know what is there in the Vedas, when Nachiketa (who has a few important Vedic rituals assigned to him) needed to ask this to Yama as related in the Kathopanishad. If there was a clear reference, Yama would not have mentioned it as a secret knowledge (IMHO)).

Comment: Thanks @SwiftPushkar, will take a look and close if it's so

Comment: @SwiftPushkar there are too many pointers to the Upanishads in that post. There is one of Rickross (not highly voted and not marked the answer) which mentions the Purusha Suktam. Should I keep this open or closed? I am hoping for more such verses and the second question is neither asked, nor answered there. I am trying to get a non-upanishad Vedic thought here.

Comment: I'll add more context to the question then. Thanks @SwiftPushkar

Comment: Also pls.do check this - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21667/what-happens-after-death-according-to-vedic-samhitas - This question is clearly duplicate of your second question.

Comment: Possibly dupe of this one: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19378/how-do-the-vedas-describe-moksha

Comment: Isha Upanishad is a part of Shukla Yajurveda Samhita. There are only 18 verses. Check if it answers your question.

Comment: @Pandya does isha upanishad mention the word moksha ?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Isha Upanishad mantra 11 says mṛtyuṁ tīrtvā
vidyayāmṛtam aśnute https://www.vedabase.com/en/iso/11 and mantra 14 says mṛtyuṁ tīrtvā sambhūtyāmṛtam aśnute https://www.vedabase.com/en/iso/14 ... mṛtyum — death; tīrtvā — surpassing; ... amṛtam — deathlessness; aśnute — enjoys. Those two verses talk about the state of moksha.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa yes attaining a permanent place is heaven is also immortality no ?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi There are many different heavens. Some of them are in this material existence, ie within this material universe. Those heavens are temporary and do not represent the state of moksha because there is death in them, namely their inhabitants will die eventually and the heaven itself will perish. However, above this material universe there is eternal imperishable world of immortality, usually called Vaikuntha in some scriptures. There inhabitants are really immortal, they live eternal life in moksha there.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa please give some vedic reference for these points.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi There are many such verses in the Upanishads, but it's a bit difficult to find in the Samhitas. Do you accept verses from the Upanishads?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18989/7853

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Well, that's not the answer to my Q which was do you find appropriate the verses from the Upanishads?

Comment: @brahmajijnasa there are casteism verses in geeta too see sankara bhashyam

Comment: @RakeshJoshi I was not talking about casteism verses but about verses from the Upanishads in which you can find references on temporary existence vs eternal existence, immortality, etc.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa but they dont say that vaikuntham alone is permanent heaven right?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Yes, Vaikuntha or personal abode of Lord Vishnu is the only eternal world that exists, it's the world of eternal moksha. It is said that Sadashivaloka is also a part (at the beginning) of Vaikuntha, and Goloka is at the top of Vaikuntha. Contrary to that, all material existence including this earth and material heavens above this earth (such as Indra's heaven) are all temporary, and perish at the end, and you can live there until you exhaust your karma or until Shiva destroys the universe.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa please cite vedic reference

Answer (score 7):

There are several things which can be interpreted as to mean Moksha/ Mukti. For eg. In the famous Purusha Suktam of Vedas, Vajasaneyi Samhita 31.18:

> वेदाहमेतं पुरुषं महान्त-
>            मादित्यवर्णं तमसः परस्तात् ।
>   तमेव विदित्वातिमृत्युमेति
>            नान्यः पन्था विद्यतेऽयनाय ॥
>
> vedāham etaṃ puruṣaṃ mahāntam ādityavarṇaṃ tamasaḥ parastāt /
>   tam eva viditvāti mṛtyum eti nānyaḥ panthā vidyate 'yanāya //
>
> I know the great Purusha, who is luminous, like the sun and beyond darkness. **Only by knowing Him does one pass over death; there is no other way to the Supreme Goal.**

This verse of Veda Samhita is used in Upanishads like Svetasvatara Upanishad 3.8.

Similarly in RigVeda 8.48.3 it is stated that Realizing Soma one attains immortality:

> अपाम सोमममृता अभूमागन्मु ज्योतिरविदाम् देवान्|
>   कि नूनमस्कान्कृणवदराति: किमु धृर्तिरमृत मर्त्यस्य।।
>  
>   We have taken Soma, **We have become Immortal, We have get that divine light (Jyoti),** What can any enemy, any mortal do to us now.

The above verse has also been used by AtharvaSiras Upanishad.

Comment: Did you make your post into Community Wiki by accident? Do you want me to reverse that for you?

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan No, I made it intentionally as most parts of it is already answered by Rickross here https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19378/how-do-the-vedas-describe-moksha ... and also question seems to be duplicate of several other answered questions...

Comment: Oh ok.  In any case, if you think it's a duplicate of something, you may want to cast a close vote.

Comment: Is immortality the same as Moksha? In Moksha you need to die at least once, right?

Comment: The PS verse is valid and it was in the linked Q in the post. However I am hoping for more such verses for such an important topic.

Comment: @user1952500 as per vedas only immortality is moksha. May be different in vedanta.

Answer (score 2):

Atharva Veda 10.8.44 says:

> akāmō dhīrō amr̥taḥ svayambhū rasēna tr̥ptō na kutaś canōnaḥ |  tam
>   ēva vidvān na bibhāya mr̥tyōr ātmānaṁ dhīram ajaraṁ yuvānam
>
> Desireless, serene, immortal, Self-existent, contented with the
>   essence, lacking nothing, is He. **One has no fear of death who has
>   known Him, the atman**—serene, ageless, youthful.

One who has realized paramatma has no fear of death anymore because he becomes immortal, ie he gets moksha or liberation from samsara of repeated births and deaths. This is the meaning of the verse.

Rig Veda 9.113.7 says:

> 9.113.07a     yátra jyótir ájasraṃ
>   9.113.07b     yásmim̐ loké súvar hitám
>   9.113.07c     tásmin mā́ṃ dhehi pavamāna
>   9.113.07d     amŕ̥te loké ákṣita
>   9.113.07e     índrāyendo pári srava
>
> O Pavamana, place me in that **deathless**, **undecaying world**
>   Wherein the light of heaven is set, and **everlasting lustre shines**.

The significant thing about this verse is that "undecaying world" and "everlasting lustre shines" indicate that the world referred to in the verse is not a material world because this material world decays or perish, ie it is destroyed in the end. And "everlasting luster shines" also indicates the same because in the perishable world no luster can shine eternally. So the verse is referring to some other world which is imperishable and eternal in existence.
Another significant thing is that it says "place me in that deathless ..." which means that the speaker of the verse wants to achieve that imperishable world in which there is no death, ie there the life is deathless. All this is clear indication that the verse is talking about the state of moksha.

I think that Vaishnava commentators of Vedanta would say that the verse is referring to the world which is known as Vaikuntha in the Puranas. It is said that Vaikuntha is the world of Lord Vishnu, it is imperishable or eternal world and souls living there are deathless or immortal living in moksha forever.